# Start Chrome in incognito mode when running capybara tests using chromedriver

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

When running cucumber scenarios, I'd like to use Chrome in Incognito mode. I've tried a few suggestions found over the internet, but neither seems to be working.

Currently, I came up to the following, and it starts chrome, but not in incognito mode

```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => %w["--incognito"]})
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps})
end
```

Any tips?

Comment: I know it's supposed to launch a new browser instance for each scenario (although it was absolutely fine to assume I don't know that - I'm very new to test automation), and it does seem to re-launch, but nevertheless, if I log in anywhere in the suit, later on it will always log me in upon page opening.
At first I was trying to clear cookies with
    `page.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies`
But it just did not work. I'm currently looking for a fast work-around, as I'm supposed to show results of my work at Monday, but most of the scenarios fail because I start already logged in.

Answer (score 7):

Digging into the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb#55), turns out it is very simple:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, switches: ['--incognito'])
  # or
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, args: ['--incognito'])
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way I have found is to add a registry key that every time you open chrome it will open in incognito mode.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"IncognitoModeAvailability"=dword:00000002

If you go to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies right click policies add folder "Google" then right click Google and add folder "Chrome."  Right click chrome add new dword "IncognitoModeAvailability" set the value to 2.

After you do this Chrome should open in incognito mode everytime.